AI is using machines to recreate historical battlefields
This is an English language sci-fi book written sometime during the past 20 years. It's about a man in the future who stumbles upon a World War I era soldier in a field. It turns out that this soldier wandered off from a battlefield that huge machines, directed by AI, are creating in the image of WW I era battlefields, the battle of Gallipoli, if I remember. Each AI created soldier is based off a real soldier from WW I. The main character gets involved and becomes a stretcher bearer or medic in the battle.
There is another element (if I'm not combining two different books!) where the main character lives in a dystopian village with other humans. Each person has a job assigned by an AI overlord and is distributed the exact supplies deemed necessary. The protagonist's job is an enforcer. He is drugged or hypnotized to put on an exoskeleton and brutally enforce the laws, but when he comes to, he doesn't remember any of it.

If Then by Matthew de Abaitua
(Published by Angry Robot in 2015)
The synopsis on the back cover of my copy:

In the near future, after the collapse of society as we know it, one English town survives under the protection of the complex algorithms of the Process, which governs every aspect of their lives. The Process both gives and takes. It allocates jobs and resources, giving each person exactly what it has calculated they will need.
The Process also decides who stays under its protection, and who must be banished to the wilderness beyond. Human life has become totally ruled by its algorithms, and James, the town bailiff, is charged with making sure the Process's orders are implemented. But now, it seems, it has started making soldiers  - terrifyingly, the Process is readying for war.

It's in two very distinct parts, which is why you were doubting if you'd remembered two different books.
The first part (titled "If"), describes the dystopian society, which is centred on the real town of Lewes, East Sussex (not far from where I live!). The protagonist's duties require him to wear "the armour" - a powered exoskeleton, which connect him via an implant directly to the Process, the distributed computing system overseeing the experimental community.
The second part (titled "Then") takes place inside the AI's recreated World War I battlefield, where the protagonist has taken on the identity of a stretcher bearer. It is indeed the Battle of Gallipoli, recreated in whole on the Sussex Downs.


Each AI created soldier is based off a real soldier from WW I.

At the end of the first chapter, one character explains to another:

As to whether he is a copy of somebody who actually lived, the Process has to work from an existing pattern. That means something or somebody who existed.



He is drugged or hypnotized to put on an exoskeleton and brutally enforce the laws, but when he comes to, he doesn't remember any of it.

Not drugged, but fitted with an implant capable of taking over his personality:

Both [the douanier] and James were big genial men who, under control of the implant, had committed violence on behalf of the community. No guilt and no bias, that was the genius of the system.


Yes yes! Thank you so much, this has been driving me crazy! Can't wait to read it again!

https://angryrobotbooks.com/books/if-then/

@Logan13 Thank you for providing such a detailed question that made me confident I had the right book :)
